# Nombre de Clases usando LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Al usar LINQ to SQL cuando pongo las tablas en el dbml las clases vienen en Plural, ¿Hay alguna manera de ponerlas en singular?

Comment: He notado que eso pasa cuando tengo una clase con el mismo nombre que una tabla, pero no te puedo dar una respuesta concreta.

Answer (score 1):

Hola en el Visual Studio haz lo siguiente:
En Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> O/R Designer cambia Pluralization of names a falso. Luego recompila la solución o genera de nuevo las entidades si el proyecto está en fase de pruebas.